How to add a professional account to Windows 10 and 11 via UWP C# without using Windows settings
I'm looking to integrate a feature into a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) application developed in C# that allows adding a professional account to a Windows 10 and 11 PC. My goal is to automate this process without having to interact with Windows settings directly, as this does not fit the user experience of my application.
I've conducted research on this topic, but I haven't found a direct solution or library that would enable me to accomplish this task. I'm open to any suggestion or alternative solution that could help me achieve my goal.
Here are some additional details about my problem:

The application should be able to handle errors and cases where adding the professional account fails.
It would be ideal if this solution was compatible with future versions of Windows.

If anyone has already accomplished a similar task or if you have advice on how to proceed, I would be grateful to know. Please feel free to provide code examples or links to useful resources.
Thank you in advance for your help.
I've explored the UWP APIs and documentation, looking for any methods or classes that could be used to programmatically add a professional account. I've also searched for any third-party libraries or tools that might offer this functionality. Unfortunately, my searches have not yielded any direct solutions or leads.
I've attempted to use the Windows.System.UserProfile namespace, hoping to find a method that could facilitate the addition of a professional account. However, the available methods and properties in this namespace do not seem to support this specific task.
I was expecting to find a straightforward API or method within the UWP framework that would allow me to add a professional account to a Windows PC without user intervention. Ideally, this would involve a few lines of code that could be integrated into my application, providing a seamless experience for the end-user.

What does "professional account" mean here? I now the wording from Microsoft and M365 Accounts. But its seems you are asking for a pure Windows Account and in tha area i'm not aware what a professional account should be.

Thank you for your question. Yes, I am referring to an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) account in my question. My goal is to automate the process of adding such an Azure AD account to a Windows PC, allowing users to log in with their Azure AD credentials without having to manually enter them through the Windows settings. This would streamline the login process for users who are already part of an organization using Azure AD for authentication.

Then you presumably need to look a the Graph API and its user management capabilities. Playing field is  here

Thank you for the suggestion. I'll look into the Graph API's user management capabilities right away.
